# Angular does not work in docker because it can not find module @angular-devkit/build-angular

Tags: angular, asp.net-mvc-4, jasmine, protractor, cucumberjs

I tried ignoring the node_modules but still is not working for me ,even after ignoring the node_modules im still facing the same error

yaml file:

```
version: '3.5'

services:
    angular-docker:
        hostname: localhost
        container_name: angular-docker
        build: ./angular-doc
        volumes:
          - './angular-doc:/usr/src/app/'
        ports:
          - '4200:4200'
```

docker file:

```
FROM node:10.12.0

RUN mkdir usr/src/app

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install -g @angular/cli@latest

COPY . .

EXPOSE 4200

CMD ng serve --host 0.0.0.0
```

Comment: 1. Run command npm install in your project folder if it's not work then
2. npm install --save-dev @angular-devkit/build-angular if it's not work then
3. npm i --only=dev if it's also not work then remove node_modules folder from your project make anew project copy node_modules folder and past it in your project then again run npm install hope its work for you.

Comment: You are missing `npm install` from your `Dockerfile` after the line where you copy your `package.json`

Answer (score 1):

You need to install **@angular-devkit/build-angular** package  as dev dependency in your angular project

```
npm install --save-dev @angular-devkit/build-angular
```

**Updated!**

you have forget to add `RUN npm install` in the docker file

```
FROM node:10.12.0
RUN mkdir usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
RUN npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
COPY . .
EXPOSE 4200
CMD ng serve --host 0.0.0.0
```

Comment: @Venkat I have update the answer hope now will work for you 

Comment: adding `RUN npm install` as a layer in the docker file worked.